# Using recursion, how do you iterate over an object to produce HTML?

Tags: html, javascript

I am trying to sort an object of key:values recursively. It seems to work , at least to the console. The code takes the object and iterates over the key value pairs. If it finds another object it calls itself to iterate over that object. The problem I have is that the subsequent call doesn't seem to produce any html, but it does show the key value pairs in the console. This is my first attempt at recursion, I'm not sure if it's the way I'm declaring variables or if I'm missing something in how recursion works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
let conditionReport = {
    weekNo:"5",
    laps:"8",
    heat:"6",
    feature:"9",
    tireSize:
        {lf:"15",lr:"16",rf:"16.5",rr:"17"},
    airPressure:
        {lf:"8",lr:"10",rf:"12",rr:"16"},
    tireTemperature:
        {lf:"9",lr:"11",rf:"13",rr:"15"},
    suspensionAdjustment:
        {lf:"4",lr:"5",rf:"6",rr:"7"},
    engineRPM:"2000",
    trackCondition:"4",
    damage2car:"3",
    suspensionAdjustment2:
        {upper:
            {lf:"4",lr:"5",rf:"6",rr:"7"},
        lower:
            {lf:"4",lr:"5",rf:"6",rr:"7"},
        },
    notes:"note 3"
}

s = x => document.getElementById(x);

const isObject = val => (typeof val === "object") ? true : false;

const getKeyValue = (obj) => {
    let html = '<ul>';
    for(let key in obj) {
        let value = obj[key]
        if(!isObject(value)){
            //console.log(isObject(value));
            console.log(key + ":" + value);
            html += '<li>' + key + ":" + value + "</li>";
        }
        else{
            if(isObject(value)){
                //console.log(isObject(value));
                console.log(key + "=>");
                getKeyValue(value);
                html += '<li>' + key + ":"+ "</li>";
            }
        }
    }
    html += "</ul>";
    s('cards').innerHTML = html;
}

getKeyValue(conditionReport);

});
```

Comment: Why are you setting innerHTML in each call of getKeyValue() ? You realize, that if you set it 100 times, only the last value will be visible at the end? I think your function has to return the value of "html" to the caller, and the caller should concatenate it with the rest and return it again, recursively.

Comment: Easy solution: Make a global variable CONSOLE and replace each `console.log(x);` with `CONSOLE+=x;` At the end, call `s('cards').innerHTML = CONSOLE;`

Comment: @IvanKuckir Easy but horrible.

Comment: @Bergi this quiestion is not about solving a problem. We have to help the OP understand programming by making small steps. During the learning process, an ugly solution, that you understand, is better than a "smooth" solution, which you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use return values:

```
const getKeyValue = (obj) => {
    let html = '<ul>';
    for (let key in obj) {
        let value = obj[key]
        if (!isObject(value)) {
            html += '<li>' + key + ":" + value + "</li>";
        } else {
            var innerValue = getKeyValue(value);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            html += '<li>' + key + ":"+ innerValue + "</li>";
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
        }
    }
    html += "</ul>";
    return html;
//  ^^^^^^
}
```

Then do

```
s('cards').innerHTML = getKeyValue(conditionReport);
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it the way I wanted.Thought that when the call happened in the else statement it would pass the if statement and update the html variable. I'm still not clear on why. Does anyone know of something I can study that would explain this model?

Comment: What do you mean by "it would pass the if statement"? Notice that `html` is a *local* variable declared with `let`, so every call - and that means also every recursive call - gets its own variable.

Comment: I thought that the recursive call would be rerun through the entire function and when it hit the if statement the html variable would be updated. I think I see what your saying, it's an entirely _new_ function call and each variable in that call has _local_ scope only within that instance.